# Check element presence in array in another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have following :

```
const arr1 = [{id: 1},{id: 2}]
const arr2 = [{id: 1},{id: 4},{id: 3}]
```

I want to check if elements in arr2 exists in arr1 or vice versa. I want to check for each element in array.

Desired output :

```
true
false
false
```

Usually it shouls give error , because one arrays length is longer than first , for the rest I want to get false

Comment: use `map` and `find`

Comment: Can you show it as an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O(N) solution with set

```
const arr1 = [{id: 1},{id: 2}]
const arr2 = [{id: 1},{id: 4},{id: 3}]
const set = new Set()

arr1.forEach((a) => set.add(a.id))

arr2.forEach((b) => {
    if (set.has(b.id)) {
       console.log("arr1 and arr2 both share"+ b.id)
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr1 = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}]
const arr2 = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 4
}, {
  id: 3
}]

let arr1id = arr1.map(i => i.id);

let result = arr2.map(a => arr1id.includes(a.id));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: a little inefficient

Comment: @epascarello Thank you for the feedback. I was in hurry :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#map` with `array#some` to check if object id in `arr2` exist in `arr1`.

```js
const arr1 = [{id: 1},{id: 2}],
      arr2 = [{id: 1},{id: 4},{id: 3}],
      result = arr2.map(({id}) => arr1.some(o => id === o.id));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

use hashmap & use below 2 methods of map in java

1. boolean containsKey(Object key)
2. V get(Object key)

`V get(Object key)` to get the object that contains the value associated with the key from map1.

`boolean containsKey(Object key)` This method returns true if some key equal to the key exists within the map, else return false [ check it in map2]

Comment: What does Java have to do with it?